# VB Textbox Entry Validation

Tags: .net, vb.net, validation, oop

I am not sure if I am approaching this problem correctly but I hope I can get a finger in the right direction as I am totally new to VB. I am trying to create a program that is supposed to calculate wattage needs for an appliance. In the textboxes I am supposed to validate the data to make sure it is within a certain range. Here is the code I have to the best of my understanding

```
Public Sub txtbxKWprice_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtbxKWprice.TextChanged

    If Double.TryParse(txtbxKWprice.Text, KiloPrice) Then
        If KiloPrice < 0.12 And KiloPrice > 0.5 Then
            MessageBox.Show("You have entered an invalid KWh price. Please enter a price between $0.12 and $0.5 ")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `If KiloPrice < 0.12 Or KiloPrice > 0.5 Then`

Comment: In winform we validate a control by handling the [Validating event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx), *not* the TextChanged event. For more info, read: [User Input Validation in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you guys, changing the And to Or did the trick. I thought I overlooked something simple but I cannot believe how simple the change was. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

By using a numericupdown control instead of textbox, you don't even need to parse the field. Just set the properties Maximum and Minimum.
By doing so the user is restricted from entering alphabetic characters, and the number of decimal digits is automatically set.